# How can I cancel a navigation command?

Tags: navigation, move-base, actionlib

[image: Rosanswers logo]

When I send a navigation request via rviz, how can I cancel the request?

Bonus points for a rostopic pub {blaj}
Double bonus multiplier for python implementation

Thanks! :D

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/57772/how-can-i-cancel-a-navigation-command?/) by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1070 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-04**:
@Dereck im using the simple_navigation_goals and in ti you can cancel goals.  Also do you know if it is possible to send a new goal before the old one is acomplished?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-11-04**:
When you submit a new goal, the old one is replaced. (At least when I used it.)

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-04**:
@Dereck thanks im having a problem when i send the goal ac.sendGoal(goal) if i dont put ac.waitForResult(); the goal is not posted or the robot does not move, when i ac.waitForResult();  it does move.  But due to this line im unable to post a new goal until the waitforresults ends.  do you have any idea why or any ideas on how to solve it? i would really appreciate it

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-11-04**:
unfortunately I do not. Perhaps there is a way to inject a debug message in the action server to make sure that your action request is really making it to the server. Then make sure nothing else is overwriting your request? That's what I would do at least. :?

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-05**:
@Dereck thanks, one more question do you now to which topic is the goal posted to? thanks

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-11-05**:
i think it is: /move_base/goal But I can't say for certain

**Comment by [ctguell](https://answers.ros.org/users/5132/ctguell/) on 2013-11-07**:
@Dereck thanks, last question is there a way to get the position of the robot?

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-11-07**:
That's called SLAM, an active research topic and there is a load of solutions.  In ROS you would typicly use gmapping, but it's going to take some effort to get running. :) Good luck!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure, how move_base handles the /move_base_simple/goal, but if it is an action, you could try sending a fully empty GoalID message to move_base/cancel.
According to [actionlib/DetailedDescription](http://www.ros.org/wiki/actionlib/DetailedDescription) this should cancel all goals.

The command thus should be fairly simple:

```
rostopic pub /move_base/cancel actionlib_msgs/GoalID -- {}
```

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 17

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dereck](https://answers.ros.org/users/2254/dereck/) on 2013-03-11**:
Perfect, I'm not sure what I did wrong last night but this worked out fine. :)